# How to get value of bootstrap switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bootstrap switch & i want to get checkbox value on click on switch. I've tried this but i din't get the value. Could you check my code bellow & let me know where i did wrong

```js
$('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch('state');
$('#price_check').click(function () {
  //alert('Test');
  var check = $(this).val();
   console.log(check)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin-bottom-10">
 <input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" id="price_check" name="pricing" data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="info" value="true">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tamara,

Bootstrap Switch has an `onSwitchChange` property that will be able to give you the *state* of the toggle. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/learnwithclyde/to2hng3f/

```
$("#price_check").bootstrapSwitch({
  onSwitchChange: function(e, state) { 
    alert(state);
  }
});
```

The above code snippet is how you would implement `onSwitchChange` property and get the `state` of the toggle control.

Comment: pls hel me in this Now how i send this state value to ajax api call
https://jsfiddle.net/pmgrfhLw/

Comment: @Tamara could you please post a new question for this instead of adding it to the comment? Usually you would want to keep the scope of a stack overflow question down to just one problem. Hope this makes sense.

Feel free to add the link to your new post here as a comment just in case anyone is looking. 

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, for your help on previous question, i'll do remember your suggestions. But i've done that by myself

Answer (score 9):

I guess all these solutions are old news as of v5?
in any case none of these work for me. So I used this solution

```
$('#orderSwitch').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Click events don't get triggered with switches. Try to use the event **switchChange.bootstrapSwitch**. This one gets triggered when changing a switch.

Also to check if it's on, I check if the class bootstrap-switch-on is applied. If not than the switch if off.

```js
$('.make-switch').bootstrapSwitch('state');
$('.make-switch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch',function () {
  var check = $('.bootstrap-switch-on');
  if (check.length > 0) {
    console.log('ON')
  } else {
    console.log('OFF')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin-bottom-10">
 <input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" id="price_check" name="pricing" data-on-color="primary" data-off-color="info" value="true">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

this code worked for me

```
   $('#price_check').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e, data) {

     alert($('#price_check').bootstrapSwitch('state'));

   });
```

Comment: This works perfectly if you have more than one switch. The other answers only works if there is one switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you will get the value of checked element..

```js
$("#boot_switch").bootstrapSwitch({
  onSwitchChange: function(e) {
    alert(e.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin-bottom-10">


  <input type="checkbox" class="make-switch" id="boot_switch" name="pricing" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="info" value="value1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#price_check").change(function () {
    var price = false;

    if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        price = true;
    } else {
        price = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this to `$("#price_check").change(function() { var price = $(this).prop('checked') }`

Answer (score 0):

try this one to get value (true or false)

```
$('#boot_switch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#price-check").prop("checked") // true / false
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.